# Docker Memory usage and Server stuck

Tags: linux, docker

We are getting an issue on Ubuntu EC2 instance, we are running 8 docker container on Amazon EC2 instance which is having 30 GB memory and 16 cores. What we observed our EC2 being stuck after 3-4 days of reboot and in the logs we are getting Memory issues. When we monitored to docker stats command it shows every Docker is running on less than 2GB (Total used 16G) on the EC2 when we ran the free –g command it shows the used memory is around 16-17GB and other memory is in buff / cache and Free is having 0.
Please let us know There is any issue or we have to do any configuration. I tried to drop the cache but it got filled in 10 minutes. 
Versions – 
Ubuntu – 16.04 ( xenial)
Docker -  17.09.0-ce

Please let me know if required more details for troubleshooting.

Thanks,

Comment: What exactly do the logs say? Also: upgrade. Ubuntu 16.04 is 4 years old. Docker 17.09 is 2.5 years old, and there have been many many bug fixes since then.

Comment: Did you report this problem to amazon support?

Comment: Thank you very much for the update. Let me check the logs and with Amazon support also we will plan for upgrade.